# How long should I wait to see a Sprint Burndown chart in RTC?

Tags: scrum, rtc

We've just set up a Rational Team Concert v3 system.  The data was loaded on Friday, but there was an issue connecting to the report data warehouses that was not fixed until today (Monday).  We've fixed it, and the data load operations seem to be finishing correctly now.

I'm desperately eager to see a burndown chart - even though I know that in 24 hours we won't really have enough data to make it useful.  I'm also eager to see just about any report from the RTC server, as we want to be able to share as much information as possible with the customer, and this is a trial for RTC as a large team tool.

How long should one expect it to take before RTC is able to show reports relating to work items?  We've already cached several data updates - but only within the last few hours.

Should we wait 24 hours?  48?  should it show up immediately?  Haven't found any good heuristics for this on the Rational site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a few things to happen to get a decent burn down chart in RTC

1. Run the Data Warehouse job (this happens every 24 hours automatically, or you can trigger it manually from the Reports page in the Admin section.
2. Get some work done - complete tasks, set Stories to Completed, etc.  The burn down is a graph over time of work done.

You should see progress on the chart after the two event above occur.

Another thing to check - is that specific burn down chart set to point to the right project and team?

If that does not work - you may want to raise the question with IBM support (sounds like something is wrong, or raise the question on the RTC forum on jazz.net

Answer (score 1):

Closure - It turns out we had several problems.  Problems included:
- incorrect account setup on the account syncing between RTC and the data warehouse - we had to both make a new account and setup more privileges for it.
- a truly messed up set of sprints.  I don't know what went wrong with the Sprints that were first set up (by default!) with the project, but they did not ever sync properly.  Moving tasks to a newly made sprint caused the tasks to show up properly in reports (after a sync), but the original sprints were simply broken.  Eventual workaround - make new sprints, same dates, and move all assigned stories/tasks to them.

The final answer was - the data should show up instantly after a sync.  If you think your sync shows new data and you don't see a change in your report, then you have a problem.

Other notes - the data in the selection fields in "edited" reports is based on the data in the warehouse.  If you don't see a sprint or release in there, it means that the report search criteria is not showing that there is data in the column that you are looking for.  Report business logic seems to vary by report - in some cases, not being able to select a sprint (or not having a sprint in the data that matches the "current iteration") - will cause empty reports.